# A tag for Lubuntu

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

I was looking the allowed tags. Why there is not a [lubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lubuntu) tag? I didn't find such tag. I don't know if the tag [lxde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxde) has the same meaning. Regards.

Answer (score 7):

The tag list isn't fixed -- anyone with [enough reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) can create new tags, but they need to be attached to a question. I added [lubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lubuntu) to a couple that looked like they could use it. However, since Lubuntu is an official Ubuntu distribution, most questions about it are probably going to be on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tags/lubuntu), a related Stack Exchange site focused on Ubuntu-specific questions